# What is John meaning by saying "I don’t have to prove anything to anyone...!!!"

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, Season 2 Episode 2 *Automatic for the People*, in the beginning of the episode John has the below conversation  with Cameron

(As per Terminator Wiki)

[image]

[image]

> John: It's healing quickly. (Inspecting Cameron's wounds)
>
> Cameron: Quicker than yours.
>
> John: What about the rest of you? You're back to normal?
>
> Cameron: Things have changed, John.
>
> John: What things?
>
> Cameron: You can't be trusted anymore.
>
> John: Me? I can't be trusted anymore?
>
> Cameron: You risked your life to fix me. That was a very dangerous
>   thing to do.  That could upset people.
>
> John: They'll have to deal with it. (John looks pointedly at Sarah and
>   Derek)

Near the end of the same episode, John & Cameron have the below conversation.

[image]

> **John: about what you said before, about not been able to trust me..,**
>
> **Cameron:  yes..**
>
> **John: I don’t have to prove anything to anyone, anyone, including you…!!**

After that, Cameron leaves without saying anything to John.
[image]

So my question is, what does John mean by saying that **"I don’t have to prove anything to anyone!"**

Comment: I think that that most recent edit may have changed the meaning of the sentence. Was Cameron the one who did not say anything?

Comment: yes Cameron didn't said anything & left john

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cameron is constantly testing John to see if he'll stack up to the John it knew.  Cameron constantly reminds John of what he would or wouldn't do.  "Future You".

So when Cameron says that things have changed, it means John has become too foolish and trustworthy of machines/terminators.  He risked his life to save "her" (it).

I think this situation has its obvious meaning at that moment (as an audience member).   But it's what we find out later in the season that adds to this whole encounter and what Cameron meant.

The whole reason Cameron came back (and this is theory, so maybe it doesn't fit your interpretation) is because "John Connor" could no longer be trusted.  John's crew, that included Jesse, were on a secret mission to make an alliance with the liquid metal terminator (that later goes back in time and becomes 'Catherine Weaver').  But because Jesse and her human crew had no idea what mission they were carrying out, they started to doubt John Connor's orders because it appeared that John was letting the terminators run the show.  It appeared that John Connor had lost his way.

The truth of the matter is that it really was being run by terminators.  Cameron was leading in John's place after she accidentally(?) killed him. "Sometimes they go bad. We don't know why."  Cameron was carrying out the mission John Connor set out for her (or Cameron purposefully killed John Connor and took his place), because she needed to be in charge and make the alliance with liquid metal in order to rebel from and defeat Skynet.

That's why Cameron went back in time, because she was trying to carry out John Connor's mission in his absence, and failed.  So she went back in time to make things right, to try again, to keep John Connor alive this time.

But things change.  John Connor put Cameron's life before his.  That DID upset people (like Jesse, whom we see come back in time to carry out her plan of keeping John Connor to be untrusting of terminators, so he doesn't make the same mistakes again).

But this can also arouse Cameron in that this human actually cares about it, actually values the life of a terminator.  Because John Connor cares for Cameron that deeply, one can imagine that this can make Cameron, a machine, an artificial intelligence (but an intelligence nonetheless) 'fall in love' with the one protecting 'HER'.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possible answers to this. Unfortunately, they all seem fairly mundane to me.

## Status as future savior of the human race

John knows that he's going to grow up to save humanity. Thus, he has no real need to prove himself since, as has been established multiple times in the Terminator continuity, the future is extremely difficult to change. Whether he likes it or not, John is basically destined to be this savior figure.

## He's a teenager

John is a teenager. Teenagers are balls of hormones who are halfway between childhood and adulthood. They're prone to dramatic statements, especially ones that establish that they don't feel like living up to the rules or which establish their "adult" independence. John's statement might have simply been a "I don't care what others think about me. I am who I am" statement.